# Deducing the return type of a standalone function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am trying to find out the return type of a non-member function. I first thought that `std::result_of` does the job, but it looks that the latter works only for callable objects. In particular, `std::result_of<decltype(f)>::type` [is not working](http://ideone.com/SHcqnf). I finally managed to come up with some code that works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

void f(int); // we deduce the returning type of this function

template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct Helper
{
    using type = Ret;
};

template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
Helper<Ret, Args...> invoke(Ret(*fp)(Args...))
{
    return {};
}

template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
using Return_Type = typename Helper<Ret, Args...>::type;

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(invoke(f))::type).name() << std::endl; // fine
}
```

I use an additional function here, the template `invoke`, which takes a pointer to the function I want to deduce the return type, and returns a "helper" structure, from which I read the actual return type.

The code seems a bit convoluted, since it involves an invoking function (although no actual evaluation is being performed). Is there any other alternative simpler and clearer/shorter way of doing this?

Comment: I am guessing you don't wan to use `decltype(f(0))`.

Comment: No, since `f` can have variable/unknown number of parameters and would like something to work for any function.

Comment: `result_of` works with function pointers fine.  `result_of<decltype(&f)(int)>::type` is `void`.  You are just using it incorrectly, and for a different purpose.

Comment: @Yakk Probably I was not very clear in the question. I wanted to deduce the return type solely from the name, without having to specify the parameter list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consulting my own [old blog posting](https://alfps.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/resultof-a-function-with-c11/) about this, I found:

```
template< class Func >
struct ResultOf
{
    typedef typename std::function<
        typename std::remove_pointer<Func>::type
        >::result_type T;
};
```

Comment: Great! I totally missed the fact that I can wrap it into a `std::function` and use the latter to process the type.

Comment: There are no SFINAE guarantees for `std::function`, which makes the above a short pretry hack.  Of course so is most code that extracts return values from functions without caring how they are called.  ;)

Comment: @Yakk: That sounds like high praise, in which case it should be directed at potatoswatter (David Krauss) here on SO. In case it's negative critique, the fault is all mine. I have to admit, I don't entirely understand what you say. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
template<typename>
struct return_t_impl;

template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct return_t_impl <Ret(Args...)> 
{
   using type = Ret;
};

template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct return_t_impl<Ret(*)(Args...)> : return_t_impl<Ret(Args...)> {};

template<typename T>
using return_t = typename return_t_impl<T>::type;
```

And the use it as:

```
using type = return_t<decltype(f)>; //type is void
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed the fact that I could have defined a partial specialization.

Comment: The 2nd specialization seems silly?  Just do `<T*>:return_t_impl<T>{}`?

Comment: The second specialization is for cases such as `auto fptr = f; using type = return_t<decltype(fptr)>;`. In this case, `fptr` is deduced to be pointer-to- function type, as opposed to, just function type.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class F>
using return_t = typename std::function<std::remove_pointer_t<std::decay_t<F>>>::result_type;
```